# NVL faster than is not null condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am asking myself if the NVL funtion is faster than the where is not null condition. I searched on Google if anybody talk about it but found nothing who respond clearly at this question.

So here's the situation I have a sql request and i want to know which is faster.
In this example I simplify the query that I have it's just to give you an idea of what i want to know.

Here's the request with nvl function

```
SELECT TA.MNT FROM TABLEA TA WHERE TA.ID NOT IN(SELECT NVL(TB.ID,-1) FROM TABLEB TB);
```

Here's the not null condition

```
SELECT TA.MNT FROM TABLEA TA WHERE TA.ID NOT IN(SELECT TB.ID FROM TABLEB TB WHERE TB.ID IS NOT NULL);
```

So which one will return faster?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't run a test and determine the answer for yourself..?

Comment: No i was just wondering if there's some possibility of one is faster than the other or if one is always faster than the other.

Comment: I tried it And it seems like that the not null condition is faster but i want to know if there's some way the the NVL function could be faster.

Comment: if there's an index on tb.id, I would assume that the 2nd query would be able to use it, whereas the first query would be less likely to use it. It entirely depends on how your tables and data are structured, though. I would be inclined to go with the second query simply because it's easier to understand, though.

Comment: Why would you want the NVL function to be faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not the same logic.

Consider that you start with `NULL, 0, 1` in `TABLEB`.
- The `NVL` version changes that to `-1, 0, 1`
- The `WHERE IS NOT NULL` changes it to `0, 1`.

This means that the `NOT IN` has fewer items to check in the `WHERE NOT NULL`, that's why it can be faster.

That said, using `NOT IN` is generally not the fastest.  The two standard options are `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT
  TABLEA.*
FROM
  TABLEA
LEFT JOIN
  TABLEB
    ON TABLEB.ID = TABLEA.ID
WHERE
  TABLEB.ID IS NULL
```

```
SELECT
  TABLEA.*
FROM
  TABLEA
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM TABLEB
               WHERE TABLEB.ID = TABLEA.ID
             )
```

Comment: Perhaps also important to note is the difference if `id` can ever be `-1`.  Then, the two forms are very, very different.  I also think the `where` form can take advantage of indexes in a way that the `nvl()` form can't.

Comment: id can't be -1 that's why I was using it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a benchmark very similar to the original queries and NVL in that case is about 47 percent slower. But agree with previous comments in real application it depends on many aspects and IS NULL is much simpler and clearer condition.